# Execute ninja build with background jobs

Tags: bash, sh, jobs, ninja

I would like to start a background process (i.e. a job) from a Ninja build command. I want the command to start the job and return (leaving the job executing in background).
I am unable to do so: the Ninja build command does not return, as if it was waiting for the job to terminate (?)

Here is my environment:

- `foo.sh`: a Bash script that starts a job printing `"-> foo"` every second

  ```bash
  bar() {
    while true; do
      echo "-> foo"
      sleep 1
    done
  }
  bar & disown
  echo "bar() running in PID=${!}"
  ```
- `build.ninja`: the Ninja configuration, with a `foo` target that calls the `foo.sh` script

  ```
  rule CUSTOM_COMMAND
    command = $COMMAND

  build foo: CUSTOM_COMMAND
    COMMAND = bash ./foo.sh
    pool = console
  ```

When executing `foo.sh` directly from the terminal, it behaves as expected:

```bash
$ sh -c 'bash ./foo.sh'
-> foo
bar() running in PID=269795
$ # foo.sh has returned, the prompt is usable
-> foo
$
-> foo
-> foo
$ # a Ctrl-C has no action
$ kill 269795
$ # job killed, no more "-> foo" printing
$
```

- The `sh -c 'bash ./foo.sh'` is used (rather than simply `bash ./foo.sh`) to be as close as possible to the Ninja processing:

> "The Ninja command variable is passed directly to sh -c"
>
> (source: https://ninja-build.org/manual.html)

But when executing the `foo` Ninja build, it does not return:

```bash
$ ninja foo
[0/1] bash ./foo.sh
-> foo
bar() running in PID=275837
-> foo
-> foo # command has not returned, the prompt is not usable
-> foo
-> foo
^Cninja: build stopped: interrupted by user. # a Ctrl-C stopped the execution
$ # process 275837 gets killed automatically
```

Why is the `ninja` command not returning?
How could I adapt `foo.sh` or `build.ninja` to reach the expected behaviour?

Tagentially, it looks like `ninja` has a "zombie" child process:

```bash
$ ps -aefxo pid,tty,ppid,pgid,sid,comm:100
...
 657811 pts/17    235551  657811  235551          \_ ninja
 657812 pts/17    657811  657811  235551              \_ sh <defunct>
```

This might be the same problem as [issue #2052](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/issues/2052) (?).